# iOS UITableView change Height Dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, height, autolayout

In my VC, I have only 1 TableView and Navigation bar on top. Am Using with AutoLayout. The cells are added dynamically. I want to change the height of table based on number of cells. For that I have added a height constraint and added reference in my VC. I call the following code whenever the tableview reloads :-

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *agentTvHeightConstraint;  

-(void) adjustHeightOfTableView {
CGFloat height = self.agentChatListTableView.contentSize.height;   // ITS 65
CGFloat maxHeight = self.agentChatListTableView.superview.frame.size.height - self.agentChatListTableView.frame.origin.y - 15; // 15 Bottom Padding to table


// if the height of the content is greater than the maxHeight of
// total space on the screen, limit the height to the size of the
// superview.

if (height > maxHeight)
    height = maxHeight;

// now set the height constraint accordingly
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    self.agentTvHeightConstraint.constant = height;
    NSLog(@"AGENT HEIGHT CONSTRAINT = %f", self.agentTvHeightConstraint.constant); 
   // LOGS 15

    [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}];
}
```

The code executes but the height of table is not changed. Why the height is not being changed ? Am I missing anything or going anywhere wrong ? Can you please point me.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should unchecked the AutoResize Subviews in your storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

inside the animation block call

```
[self.tableView layoutIfNeed];
```

it should work

Comment: Tried calling before [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints]; and/or after [self.view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];, but no changes - height is not changed.

Answer (score 0):

As have used AutoLayout, had set constraints for `Trailing`, `Leading`, `Top` and `Bottom`. Changed the `Bottom` constraint from `Equal` to `Greater Than or Equal` . That did the trick. Code is unchanged.

Hope this helps someone.